# C++ IO vs Java IO

Tags: java, c++, ios, file-io

Note that this is NOT a "better-than" discussion.

I'm a Java programmer, and it makes me feel incredibly dumb not to know how to do very much C++ file IO.

I need to make very simple adapter for XML parsers, just like code below says

In Java, I could just use:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(xmlInputStream));

String xml = "";
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  xml += line + "\n";
}

return xmlParser11.parse(xml);
```

Biggest question for me is what to do with this `reader` in C++

Thanks very much!

edit cutted ;)

Comment: So, how come your first two scentences are almost identical to those of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954176/java-line-io-vs-c-io)?

Comment: I used that quiestion as "introduction" to my own

Comment: This question explains IO in C++ quite well. With which part are you having trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give a gentler introduction, the following C++ code is mimicking your Java code as much as sensible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream xmlInputStream("input.xml"); // or istringstream or istream
    std::string xml;
    std::string line;
    while(getline(xmlInputStream, line))
    {
        xml += line + "\n";
    }
    //return xmlParser11.parse(xml);
    std::cout << xml << '\n';
}
```

But of course one doesn't have to loop to read an input stream into a string in C++: the input stream can be represented as a pair of iterators, which can be used in many different ways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream xmlInputStream("input.xml");
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> beg(xmlInputStream), end;
    std::string xml(beg, end);
    std::cout << xml << '\n';
}
```

But often a temporary string object is not even needed: a C++ parser could operate on an input stream or on a pair of iterators directly.

Comment: Wow, great. Can I use *pointer to* `ifstream` in place of giving *name of file*? If yes - how?

Comment: The usual idiom would be to use a reference to the `istream` base class of `ifstream`.  That way, you can also read other types of input streams.

Comment: @dantuch you'd pass a reference to istream into your function, like so: `std::string StreamToString(std::istream& stream)`. Then it can be called as `StreamToString(xmlInputStream)` or even `StreamToString(std::cin)`.

Comment: Cubbi big thanks for big help. Can you please take a look at edit in my question?

Comment: @dantuch: There are a few things a C++ programmed would do differently, but the main issue is that like many Java programmers, you're misusing `new` and generating memory leaks both times. Try not using it at all: https://ideone.com/YaaCw

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading from a file, you could do it like this:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile.xml");
std::stringstream xml;

std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<char>(xml));
```

This will read the entire file into the `std::stringstream` `xml`, including line-breaks and all (like in your sample-code). You can then access it as an `std::string` using `xml.str()`.

Comment: I think you wanted to write either `istream_iterator<string>` or `istream_iterator<char>` and same for `ostream_iterator`. Remember these are class templates, and so require type arguments!

Comment: Not only that, but they will remove all white space.  Using `streambuf_iterator` would be a better solution, but in the end, reading a file just to initialize a `stringstream` doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is using STL -- did you mean to ask about C++ or do you want the C equivalent (i.e. using fopen, fread etc)?

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string line;
  string xml;
  ifstream myfile("example.txt");

  if( myfile.is_open() ) {
    while( myfile.good() ) {
      getline (myfile,line);
      xml += line + "\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else
     cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same thing in C++:

```
std::ifstream reader( xmlInputStream.c_str() );
if ( !reader.is_open() ) {
    //  error handling here...
}

std::string xml;
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( reader, line ) ) {
    xml += line + '\n';
}
```

It's probably not the best solution, but it's already fairly
good.  I'd probably write something like:

```
std::string xml(
    (std::istringstream_iterator<char>( reader )),
    (std::istringstream_iterator<char>()) );
```

(Note that at least one set of the extra parentheses are needed,
due to an anomaly in the way C++ would parse the statement
otherwise.)

Or even:

```
std::string
readCompleteFile( std::istream& source )
{
    return std::string(
        std::istringstream_iterator<char>( source ),
        std::istringstream_iterator<char>() );
}
```

(Look ma, no variables:-)!)  Both of these solutions preserve
the newlines in the original file, so you don't need to put them
back in after reading.

Comment: Big thanks for big help. Can you please take a look at edit in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Several comments on the edit:

- It would be extremely rare
  to take an `std::ifstream&` as an argument, rather than an
  `std::istream&`.  About the only time you see `std::ifstream` is
  when defining the object itself.
- The error checking as to whether you've successfully opened
  the stream or not belongs where you opened, not in some function
  called with (what should be) an `std::istream&`.  (You can't
  check whether an `std::istream` is open or not, because for many
  stream types, the concept of "open" doesn't exist.)
- It's not clear what the sematncis of `XML` are: are they
  value, in which case it supports copy and assignment, you
  never allocate one dynamically, and you return by value from
  `XMLParser11::Parse`; or is this some sort of entity object, in
  which case, you return a pointer (or possibly an
  `std::auto_ptr`, in order to make especially sure that the
  client knows that he is responsible for deleting it.
- At any case, if `XML` is allocated dynamically, you should
  keep it in an `std::auto_ptr` in `XMLParser11::Parse`, to ensure
  that it is correctly destructed if there is an exception
  somewhere between its allocation and the return.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a destructor for `BufferedReader` that would destroy any used resources and free any memory used during that object's lifetime. After I did that, then I would call `delete` on my `BufferedReader` object.

Of course, that would be if you were using C++ only.

Comment: You could just use `ifstream`, and then you would not have to implement anything at all (except your own application).

Comment: I didn't knew that there is `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`. I'm realy suprissed that those can be found in C++ too :). but readLine is a bit different - `readLine(String& ret)` what's that argument? and how to change my loop to make it work the same as it did in Java? ... I want to xmlInputStream be a pointer to some kind of stream (ifstream is ok I guess)

Comment: @dantuch: You can implement your own BufferedReader but it is not native to C++. The way your question is written is you are showing what you created in C++ and you want to know what to do with the reader when you are finished.

Comment: The C++ class `streambuf` and its derived classes implement both the `InputStreamReader` and the `BufferedReader`.  One could argue that this isn't really clean design, but it does make for significantly better performance---a real issue when `iostream` was designed.  And managing the buffer well sometimes requires knowledge of the ultimate source, so the decision can be justified on a design level as well.  (Sort of, anyway.)

Comment: Big thanks for big help. Can you please take a look at edit in my question?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with looking [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-text-file-line-by-line-each-line-to-string-array-126337/).